# C2DM push notification without MQTT,UA in android api level <8

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

Is it possible to build c2dm in android api level <8. I do not want to use third party library like MQTT, Xtiffy UA etc.  Is there any library or file which i use in my project and than i can use c2dm push notification in my <8 api level.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way, what you could do is use a library like [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) to create server-client 'chat like' communication but the problem its time consuming to build it and maintain it. Other solution for third party services is [Xtify](http://www.xtify.com) they provide a free Push notification (only advance feature that you pay for) for android 1.6 and above also complete c2dm solution.

Comment: Xtify is paid but i have already make sample application of MQTT but i want build c2dm in 1.6 or above if it is possible.

Comment: i am using xtify in my App and i am not paying anything. AFAIK using c2dm in less than 2.2 is not possible because C2DM use the same connection Google use for gmail, calender, talk etc.. and the change that let c2dm use this connection is only available for 2.2 and above. So you could create your own solution or use 3rd party library.

Comment: this same connection also in 1.6 because it also use gmail and android market than why we can't use c2dm in 1.6.